# Java method to file

Tags: java

I'm writing code that prints you combination of numbers from 1 to n. In console it works perfectly fine, but i need to print it into file. 
What should i do?

Code:

```
public class Permutace {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("your number: ");
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int[] sequence = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sequence[i] = i + 1;
        }

        permute(sequence, 0);
    }

    public static void permute(int[] a, int k){

        if (k == a.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(a[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            for (int i = k; i < a.length; i++) {
                int temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;

                permute(a, k + 1);

                temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "but i need to print it into file" , what and where is file?? what is the error??

Comment: @Dimitris , idk what he mean by file, until then you cant say it is duplicate.

Comment: What kind of a file are you talking about?

Comment: @Akceptor where in code you see file mentioned, except title?? You can't say it is duplicate.

Comment: @CommonMan He says it works in console but he needs to write it to a file, the duplicate shows how to do that.

Comment: @Op says he wants to print into a file not write into a file, moreover OP is not clear in what he want to say here, you just cant keep saying duplicate to unclear questions. there is a hell lot of difference to write and print.

Comment: @CommonMan The question asks to print numbers in a file, the same way that he prints in the console. So unless I miss something it is just a text file in the local. Also, it is possible duplicate.

Comment: @CommonMan: the OP has all the time in the world to [edit] their question to clarify it.

Comment: @CommonMan he asks how to writhe the output into file. I assume if someone doesn't know how to do that he won't put that in code

Comment: @Akceptor , question mentioned the word "print" not "write" , there is hell a lot of difference between both implementation, anyways as you all wish do it :).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("your number: ");
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int[] sequence = new int[N];

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");


        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sequence[i] = i + 1;
        }

        permute(sequence, 0);
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void permute(int[] a, int k){

        if (k == a.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                writer.println(a[i]);
            }
            writer.println();
        } else {
            for (int i = k; i < a.length; i++) {
                int temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;

                permute(a, k + 1);

                temp = a[k];
                a[k] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this is so simple that he wasn't asking for this.

Comment: Well, by the title and the question, It looks like he wants to create a file with the contents of the console

Comment: I don't know why he would ask for such a thing at all. There is at least dozens examples how to do it on SO alone.

Comment: Sometimes it's better to just provide an answer, specially an easier one, rather than advocate on what should and not be a question.

Comment: Are you talking to me? @Tom

Comment: @MS90 No, to Bruno. His code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: A code dump isn't useful. An incorrect one even less so.